# Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-android-extensions

i want to insert menu gridview in tablayout with kotlin. i have been searching for many references in google but it wont help, still getting 1 error in `adapter = FoodAdapter(this, foodsList)`. it says "Type missmatch : inferred type as fragmentHome but Context was expected". this is my code for fragmentHome.kt

```
package com.example.ako.nextbrilliantgeneration

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_fragment_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.menu_entry.view.*

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

class fragmentHome : Fragment() {


var adapter: FoodAdapter? = null
var foodsList = ArrayList<Menu>()


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?


): View? {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_home, container, false)

    foodsList.add(Menu("Coffee", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Espersso", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("French Fires", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Honey",R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Strawberry", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Sugar cubes", R.drawable.profile))
    adapter = FoodAdapter(this, foodsList)

    gvFoods.adapter = adapter


}

class FoodAdapter : BaseAdapter {
    var foodsList = ArrayList<Menu>()
    var context: Context? = null


    constructor(context: Context, foodsList: ArrayList<Menu>) : super() {
        this.context = context
        this.foodsList = foodsList
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return foodsList.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return foodsList[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val food = this.foodsList[position]

        var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var foodView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.menu_entry, null)
        foodView.imgFood.setImageResource(food.image!!)
        foodView.tvName.text = food.name!!

        return foodView
    }
}
```

}

is there any solution?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your adapter takes in a **non-null** `Context`, but you're passing in a `Fragment`. You could try passing in your activity from your fragment, either:

```
adapter = FoodAdapter(activity!!, foodsList)
```

Or if you have the latest support library:

```
adapter = FoodAdapter(requireActivity(), foodsList)
```

You're getting unreachable error because you return from the method too early, simply move it to the bottom:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    foodsList.add(Menu("Coffee", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Espersso", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("French Fires", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Honey",R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Strawberry", R.drawable.profile))
    foodsList.add(Menu("Sugar cubes", R.drawable.profile))
    adapter = FoodAdapter(this, foodsList)

    gvFoods.adapter = adapter

    // move this line to last
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_home, container, false)
}
```

Comment: this makes the error was gone, but another warning showed up it says unreachable code in : foodsList.add(Menu("Sugar cubes", R.drawable.profile)) adapter = FoodAdapter(this, foodsList) gvFoods.adapter = adapter

Comment: Yeah that will be your coding error. Just move that return after setting the adapter.

Comment: Do not use requireActvity() unless you want an exception to be thrown in your code in the case that the activity is null. Better to use `?.let` to check for null before calling the method.

Comment: Well I guess I'm only trying to help with type mismatch error and not nullable issue. But if I had, I could argue that moving adapter creation to `onAcivityCreated` so that `requireActivity` would never return null, or to `onAttach` so that `requireContext` would never return null, instead showing a blank recycler view if somehow they are null, but then I again I decided to keep the answer as simple as possible. It may help others who are confused with mistype error to understand better.

Answer (score 3):

The error is clear enough you try to pass `this` which refer to `Fragment object` but your adapter needs `Context` then try to pass `Activity` that `extends from Context`.

**Replace this line**

```
adapter = FoodAdapter(this, foodsList)
```

**With**

```
adapter = FoodAdapter(getActivity(), foodsList)
```

**Update**

> calls to Java get and set methods that can be replaced with the use of Kotlin synthetic properties.

```
getActivity()  --> activity
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, its really helpfull.
but can you help me for the detail?
now i know the problem, but i dont know what im going to do cause im newbie. 
i just replace `this` with `getActivity()` and still have type missmatch

Comment: `adapter = FoodAdapter(activity, foodsList)` shall fix mismatch error

Comment: still not fix the problem yet sir

Comment: Try `Clean & run` and feedback?

Comment: i try to clean and run but nothing change. the error was gone if i replace `adapter = FoodAdapter(this, foodsList)` With `adapter = FoodAdapter(activity!!, foodsList)`. but another warning showed up, it says "Unreachable code" in : `foodsList.add(Menu("Sugar cubes", R.drawable.profile)) adapter = FoodAdapter(activity!!, foodsList) gvFoods.adapter = adapter`

Answer (score 1):

This is a great update to help developers who are writing in Kotlin. The `getActivity` method has been annotated with `@Nullable` to better support Kotlin null-safety. Before, this method could return null and would therefore cause an `IllegalStateException` in Kotlin code because a null object would be used where a non-null type was expected.

To best handle these cases for methods that have been annotated with `@Nullable`, use the `let` operator to unwrap the nullable into a non-null object.

```
getActivity()?.let { adapter = FoodAdapter(it, foodList) }
```

DO NOT use `requireActivity()` to "ensure" a non-null activity because this method will throw an exception if your activity does happen to be null.

Comment: So we shouldn't use `requireActivity()` at all?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky no, it is useful in say a Fragment's onActivityCreated lifecycle method where, practically, if the Activity is null then Android itself is broken.

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment class you should use following way:

```
mFargmentSettingBinding.txtAppVersionCode.setText(Static.getAppVersion(activity!!))
```